# what do header linux/magic.h and linux/posion.h do?

Tags: linux

Linux headers linux/magic.h and linux/poison.h seems to be strange. There's nothing but macros that can be expanded into constants in there.

And it seems that some user-space app depend on them.

I can't understand what these 2 headers do.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801360/what-is-the-meaning-of-0xdead000000000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linux/magic.h defines constants used to identify the format of a filesystem (by identifying magic number in superblock). See more [here](https://superuser.com/questions/239088/whats-a-file-systems-magic-number-in-a-super-block).
linux/poison.h defines constants used in pointer poisoning, ie. pointers with specified values can't be used without a crash and are somewhat easier to track. See another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801360/what-is-the-meaning-of-0xdead000000000000).